# Adding a value to a queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my Django form I have a ModelChoiceField for employees, but I want a choice in the dropdown for 'all' employees. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

```
employees = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Employees.objects.all())
```

First attemptI tried

```
employees = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Employees.objects.values())
```

but I get a 'too many objects to unpack' error

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't want ModelMultipleChoiceField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
employees = forms.ChoiceField(choices = [(emp['id'], emp['full_name']) 
            for emp in Employees.objects.values('id', 'full_name')])
```

The **too many objects to unpack** error raised because every cell of chioces must only contains two value similar below:

```
[(1, 'Eric Manson'), (2, 'Julia Rose'), (3, 'Saadi Khorshid'), ...]
```

But `Employees.objects.values()` unpacking all fields in **dictionary** form.